# How can I tell if my rabbit broke her toe?

Tags: rabbits, injury

I really need immediate help.

I live in India and adopted a rabbit 2 years ago. One year ago she gave birth to 6 healthy babies.

Her diet includes biscuits, fruits like  apple, cucumber, guava, raisins, watermelon, mango, and chiku. We provide a a local green leafy vegetable which she  loves and is very nutritious. Other than that she eats carrot, potato, tomato, and the leaves of cauliflower in winter.

She stays in cage but most of the time we let her out.

Recently I have noticed one thing in her leg. Her left foot' s little toe doesnt seem okay as compared to her right foot. The left foot's little toe seems to hang loose. She does not have any strength in that toe.

What should i do?
Should i be worried?

Comment: Is there a reason you haven't taken her to a vet?

Answer (score 2):

If you are concerned about your rabbit's health you should take her to a vet - it isn't really possible to diagnose if she has broken her finger online.

Answer (score 2):

Rabbits who live on wire bottom cages frequently get broken toes.  This can be limited by trimming toe nails regularly and decreasing startling occurrences.

Scenario: A rabbit with long toe nails is on a wire bottom cage, something scares the rabbit and she jumps. Her toe nail hangs on the wire mesh and the toe is broken.

You should also read some of the posts about [rabbit diet](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rabbits+diet)