# What do I do if my guinea pig has a swelled toenail? Is this rare?

Tags: guinea-pigs, rodents

[image][Heidi's toenail (Zoom in if you need to)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9AZd.jpg)I woke up to trim my guinea pigs', Heidi(female), toenails, and noticed that her skin was getting really big and swelled up around it. I tried trimming it, and it really hurt her. I don't know if I should trim it, or go see a vet. If this is a bad thing, I will most definititly see a vet without risk of hurting my piggie, but I need to know if I could just buy medicine, or trim it and give Heidi some sort of attention or care.

P.S. For all of you guiinea pig lovers out their(I am one myselfC:)Don't worry if you think Heidi is lonely! She has a sister, Hazel, and they live together in a spacioius and happy cage. No need to worry!

Comment: Its not really clear from the picture, the headline and the actual question text: is it the **nail** itself that is thicker than usual or the **tissue** surrounding the nail that is swollen?

Comment: The nail is really thick, and the skin is starting to stretch around it a little bit, I'm not a vet so I don't really know but that's my best guess. I have another picture that I will change it to.

Answer (score 1):

You should go to the vet, that looks like swelling from an infection.

Comment: Okay, thank you! Would you happen to know what the possible infection could be?

Comment: @SheridanGapp it is really hard to tell by a photo.  Anything that could cause a broken toe to also lead to an infection.  See [this](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/13506/13) and [this](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/6987/13)

Comment: I do not have a wire bottom cage it is just smooth and I have bedding, but I do have a wood platform that my piggies love to climb on. They also climb that wooden ladder in the picture. She may have sracpen it.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to my guinea pig once. He bumped his foot on the wooden bridge and got a swollen toe. The vet gave him antibiotics and after some time the swollen disappeared. Later we changed the bridge to a lower one and it never happened again.